# File Transfer using TCP - Server side

Tags: python

I am trying to send the file from server to client but the server is not sending the file. Can someone help me out ?

```
while 1:

    # server waits for incoming requests; new socket created on return
    connection_client_socket, addr = connection_server_socket.accept()

    # Read the name of the file sent from the client
    file_name_client = connection_client_socket.recv(1024)

    file_name = file_name_client.decode('utf-8')
```

I hope the program works till this line properly.

```
    file_name_to_look_for = file_name
    file_search_status = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\welcome\\Desktop\\Arun\\'):
        if file_name_to_look_for in files:
            file_search_status = 1
            print("File found at : %s" % join(root, file_name_to_look_for))
            break
    if file_search_status == 0:
        ## 
        #   The file requested by the client is not found on the server
        ##
        capitalized_file_name_client = "FILE NOT FOUND".encode()
        connection_client_socket.send(capitalized_file_name_client)
    else:
        #   The file has been found on the server
        #   send notification to client stating that the file transfer begins
        capitalized_file_name_client = "FILE FOUND".encode()
        connection_client_socket.send(capitalized_file_name_client)
        begin_file_transfer(file_name,connection_client_socket)

# close the TCP connection
# welcoming socket continues
connection_client_socket.close()
```

Comment: UDP is not your best choice for sending files

Comment: UDP isn't nearly as reliable as TCP, you're going to lose packets. Do you have a specific reason you can't use TCP for this?

Comment: I am sorry, this is a TCP code. The server is getting the file name from client but the server is not sending back the contents of the file back